# New to scripting

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ms-office

I have two commands I have to run in CMD.  I also need to run them remotely.  I will add the .bat file to the C:\ of the remote computer as well.  This is actually a fix for Windows 7 to 10 1809 migrations that breaks protected view in Office if anyone wants to know.

```
icacls "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll" /grant *S-1-15-2-1:(OI)(CI)RX

icacls "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll" /grant *S-1-15-2-1:(OI)(CI)RX
```

This is what I came up with as being my first attempt at creating a bat file on my own.  I am so new to this it's almost embarrassing but you have to start somewhere.

```
c:\
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64
start cmd.exe /k icacls "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll" /grant *S-1-15-2-1:(OI)(CI)RX
start cmd.exe /c icacls "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll" /grant *S-1-15-2-1:(OI)(CI)RX
pause
```

This also has to be run as admin.

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title.

Comment: I'm lost as to what your question is.  I don't see any question marks anywhere.  Please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry this is my first post.  I don't use these types of forums too much.  I am basically needing help writing the code to run the command line code from a remote location and as admin.  My only attempt is not good and I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is for you to use PsExec from the [SysInternals Suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite). You mentioned trying to run command line commands from a remote location as admin, so this is why I am suggesting it. You can use it to run the icacls command or other commands remotely.

Here are some links to some documentation about PsExec:

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
[ss64 Documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html)

And a link to an artice written by Mark Russinovich (Sysinternals Creator) on using PsExec:

[PsExec Article](https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/psexec)

Now for the usage for your specific need:

`psexec -accepteula \\[IP Address or Hostname] -u [domain\username] -p [Password] cmd.exe`

Example with the options filled in:

`psexec -accepteula \\192.168.1.3 -u win7\bob -p P@ssword cmd.exe`

This command will will allow you to open a remote command shell on the machine you want to execute the icacls commands. From there, you just run the icacls commands as if you were sitting at the remote machine. I recommend reading up in the links provided to understand what each switch does.

Or you can try this, which combines the above with your icacls commands and executes it all at once. I have not tested the command below, but it SHOULD work. This is all one command by the way, so make sure it is copied as one line.

`psexec -accepteula \\[IP Address or Hostname] -u [User] -p [Password] cmd /c "icacls "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll" /grant *S-1-15-2-1:(OI)(CI)RX & icacls "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll" /grant *S-1-15-2-1:(OI)(CI)RX"`

I know this isn't a batch script, but it could help accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for help.  I am going to give it a shot.